# Resampling Landsat 8 band 8 to 30m resolution (to same res as other bands)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, landsat, resampling

I'm running a script in Matlab where I need to compare different Landsat 8 bands. The matrices of each band must match up, but I'm using band 8 which is at double the resolution of the others, and therefore has double the number of cells.

It was suggested to me that I use ArcMap to resample the band 8 to 30m res but I'm not sure how. It was suggested that I use 'extract by mask' but I'm not sure how this would work as I don't want to extract an roi, I want the whole image resampled.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Resample tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/resample.htm) (available at all license levels) in ArcMap.

Here is a [detailed Esri article](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/spatial-analyst/performing-analysis/cell-size-and-resampling-in-analysis.htm) about resampling.

You could also use something like [r.resample](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.resample.html) from GRASS, which can be accessed in [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/), which is a free and open-source alternative.